# Ember Binded Controller Computed Property Doesn't get Updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, coffeescript

I saw this way of doing a drag & drop UI/UX using ember.js http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/5uX9H/
This is like a shopping cart.

I'm using the latest version of ember.js "1.5.0" and to give more background I'm using Rails as a backend for this ember app.

The problem here is that whenever I drag a product, the SimpbroAdmin.ProductDropTarget view doesn't update. And it seems like the binded controller property "SimpbroAdmin.ProductsController.currentDragItem" (Computed property) doesn't get updated which is causing the problem.

The main difference between the fiddle and my implementation is that I use data-store as opposed to the fiddle's hardcoded array of JSON contents.

These are the files:

application.js.coffee

```
window.SimpbroAdmin = Ember.Application.create()
```

products.handlebars

```
<ul>                                                                             
  {{#each}}                                                                      
    <li>                                                                         
      {{#view SimpbroAdmin.ProductView contentBinding="this"}}                   
        {{name}}                                                                 
        {{description}}                                                          
        <span style="color:red">                                                 
        {{isAdded}}                                                              
        </span>                                                                  
      {{/view}}                                                                  
    </li>                                                                        
  {{/each}}                                                                      
</ul>                                                                    

{{#view SimpbroAdmin.ProductDropTarget dragContextBinding="SimpbroAdmin.ProductsController.currentDragItem"}}
  Shopping Cart                                                                  
  <div style="height: 20px">{{view.helpText}}</div>                              
{{/view}}

{{#each SimpbroAdmin.CartController.cartItems}}                                  
  {{#view SimpbroAdmin.ProductView contentBinding="this"}}                       
    {{view.name}}                                                                
  {{/view}}<br />                                                                
{{/each}}
```

products_controller.js.coffee

```
SimpbroAdmin.ProductsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(                  
  actions:                                                                       
    addProduct: (name, description) ->                                           
      store = @store                                                             
      product = store.createRecord "product",                                    
        name: name                                                               
        description: description                                                 
      product.save()                                                             

  currentDragItem: Ember.computed((key, value) ->                                
    @findProperty "isDragging", true                                             
  ).property("@each.isDragging").cacheable()                                     

  productsInCart: Ember.computed((key, value) ->                                 
    @filterProperty "isAdded", true                                              
  ).property("@each.isAdded").cacheable()                                        
)
```

product_view.js.coffee

```
SimpbroAdmin.DragNDrop = Ember.Namespace.create()                                
SimpbroAdmin.DragNDrop.cancel = (event) ->                                       
  event.preventDefault()                                                         
  false                                                                          

SimpbroAdmin.DragNDrop.Draggable = Ember.Mixin.create(                           
  attributeBindings: "draggable"                                                 
  draggable: "true"                                                              
  dragStart: (event) ->                                                          
    dataTransfer = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer                              
    dataTransfer.setData "Text", @get("elementId")                               
    return                                                                       
)                                                                                

SimpbroAdmin.DragNDrop.Droppable = Ember.Mixin.create(                           
  dragEnter: SimpbroAdmin.DragNDrop.cancel                                       
  dragOver: SimpbroAdmin.DragNDrop.cancel                                        
  drop: (event) ->                                                               
    event.preventDefault()                                                       
    false                                                                        
)                                                                                

SimpbroAdmin.ProductView = Ember.View.extend(SimpbroAdmin.DragNDrop.Draggable,   
  tagName: "span"                                                                
  # .setDragImage (in #dragStart) requires an HTML element as the first argument 
  # so you must tell Ember to create the view and it's element and then get the  
  # HTML representation of that element.                                         
  dragIconElement: Ember.View.create(                                            
    attributeBindings: ["src"]                                                   
    tagName: "img"                                                               
    src: "http://twitter.com/api/users/profile_image/twitter"                    
  ).createElement().get("element")                                               

  dragStart: (event) ->                                                          
    @_super event                                                                
    # Let the controller know this view is dragging                              
    @set "isDragging", true                                                      
    console.log(@.content)                                                       
    # Set the drag image and location relative to the mouse/touch event          
    dataTransfer = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer                              
    dataTransfer.setDragImage @get("dragIconElement"), 24, 24                    

  dragEnd: (event) ->                                                            
    # Let the controller know this view is done dragging                         
    @set "isDragging", false                                                     
)              

SimpbroAdmin.ProductDropTarget = Ember.View.extend(SimpbroAdmin.DragNDrop.Droppable,
  tagName: "div"                                                                 
  classNames: ["dropTarget"]                                                     
  classNameBindings: ["cartAction"]                                              
  helpText: null                                                                 
  # This will determine which class (if any) you should add to                   
  # the view when you are in the process of dragging an item.                    
  cartAction: Ember.computed((key, value) ->                                     
    if Ember.isEmpty(@get("dragContext"))                                        
      @set "helpText", "(Drop Zone)"                                             
      console.log('empty')                                                       
      return null                                                                
    unless @getPath("dragContext.isAdded")                                       
      @set "helpText", "(Drop to Add)"                                           
      console.log('add')                                                         
      "cart-add"                                                                 
    else if @getPath("dragContext.isAdded")                                      
      @set "helpText", "(Drop to Remove)"                                        
      console.log('remove')                                                      
      "cart-remove"                                                              
    else                                                                         
      @set "helpText", "(Drop Zone)"                                             
      null                                                                       
  ).property("dragContext").cacheable()                                          
  drop: (event) ->                                                               
    viewId = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("Text")                    
    view = Ember.View.views[viewId]                                              
    # Set view properties                                                        
    # Must be within `Ember.run.next` to always work                             
    Ember.run.next this, ->                                                      
      view.set "content.isAdded", not view.get("content.isAdded")                

    @_super event                                                                
)
```

cart_controller.js.coffee

```
SimpbroAdmin.CartController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(                      
  # Sort desc by name                                                            
  content: Ember.computed((key, value) ->                                        
    cartItems = @get("cartItems")                                                
    unless Ember.empty(cartItems)                                                
      cartItems.sort (a, b) ->                                                   
        if (a.get("name").toLowerCase()) < (b.get("name").toLowerCase())         
          -1                                                                     
        else                                                                     
          1                                                                      

  ).property("cartItems").cacheable()                                            
  cartItemsBinding: "SimpbroAdmin.ProductsController.productsInCart"             
)
```

product.js

```
SimpbroAdmin.Product = DS.Model.extend({                                         
  name: DS.attr('string'),                                                       
  description: DS.attr('string'),                                                
  photo: DS.attr('string'),                                                      
  in_sale: DS.attr('boolean'),                                                   
  in_stock: DS.attr('boolean')                                                              
});
```

Comment: My guess is that you are conflating view, controller, and model properties. Try changing `@set "isDragging", true ` to `@set "controller.isDragging", true ` Get this set up on a fiddle or jsbin so we can hack at it for you. :)

Comment: Also Ember (and really all un-minified JS) is ridiculously easy to debug in any of the big-3 browsers. Set a break-point inside the computed property and then follow the trail down the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code looks based on something pre Ember 1.0.

There are a lot of things that need work, I'd recommend going through the Ember guides.

Here's a few tips:

`cacheable()` is no longer necessary on your computed properties

You should use `get`/`set` and not `getPath`/`setPath`.

You should avoid using globals and try out ember's router.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vugesoso/4/edit